Unknown lifecycle phase ".version". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal: Maven
I am writing a workflow file for CI/CD with GitHub actions. For building the Docker image, I need the project version from the pom.xml, as done here-
https://youtu.be/UtEHSngmdHA?t=6741 and as done in the extract version action of the build-image phase- https://github.com/ali-bouali/book-social-network/blob/ci/pipeline/.github/workflows/pipeline-backend.yml.
Similarly, I wrote a workflow file stage-
 build-image:
    runs-on: ubuntu
    name: Build Docker Image
    needs: build #-build-image step must run after build
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4 
        with: 
          fetch-depth: 0 
      - name: Setup JDK
        uses: actions/setup-jdk@v4
        with: 
          java-version: '21' 
          distribution: 'corretto'
      - name: Extract project version
        id: extract_version #-give id to be used later
        run: |
          cd examsoft
          echo "VERSION=$(./mvnw -q -Dexec.executable='echo' -Dexec.args='${project.version}' --non-recursive exec:exec)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

But, the command-
./mvnw -q -Dexec.executable='echo' -Dexec.args='${project.version}' --non-recursive exec:exec

Is giving me an error-
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".executable=echo". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: pre-clean, clean, post-clean, validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException

I am using Java 21 and Maven version 3.9.5.
My project's pom.xml is-
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.examsoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>examsoft</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>examsoft</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod2</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>42.7.3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>


Interestingly I do not rely on the pom to have a good version. Instead I use gitversion to get a semantic version number, then inject it into the pom before build.

Does this answer your question? How to get Maven project version to the bash command line

For maven the command is mvn exec:exec rest are properties to exec plugin. Give it a shot

@queeg can elaborate a little bit, about your method. How its done?

@ayush Check https://gitversion.net/docs/learn/why - you currently have the version inside the build script pom.xml

I'had similar issue.
I solved using double quotes in expression value.
not working:
.\mvnw org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.1.0:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version

working:
.\mvnw org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.1.0:evaluate -Dexpression="project.version"

